# Make Apache Web Server load new images and CSS

Tags: css, apache, image, load, dynamic

How to make apache web server dynamically load new CSS and images? The purpose is to change the look and feel of portals in a cluster of load balanced web server instances, dynamically. I get a list of files that are changed and would be pushing to web server instances. Now the web server should, display the new CSS and images instead of old or cached.

Please let me know what changes I have to make in the html, apache server settings, cache settings etc. to make this happen.

Thanks in advance.

Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of changes built up, and flush the entire cache. This is the least headache way to do it.